# Quicksort in C with unit testing framework

Tags: c, unit-testing, reinventing-the-wheel, error-handling, quick-sort

This is my quicksort
There are many like it but
This quicksort is mine.

So, quicksort, in C, with a big framework to test it six ways from Sunday. Passed the tests nicely, but there may be warts, or subtle mistakes I didn’t think of, or code that’s hard to follow, or just better ways to do things. Have at it.

EDIT: Forgot another issue: I’m not handling memory allocation errors gracefully in this code. Suggestions on how professional-level production code might handle them are welcome. I’m thinking that functions using `malloc()` should return a value to be checked, and set `errno` to `ENOMEM`.

My quicksort implementation is somewhat slower than the library function; that’s only to be expected; library code is optimized and I don’t try to pick a good pivot with median-of-3 or such. No need to critique that, I wanted to keep it simple.

```
/* Quicksort implementation and testing framework */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* 0: use qsort correctly, to test the rest of the framework
 * 1: mess up the sort sometimes, to test if sorting errors are caught
 * 2: mess up the sentinels sometimes, to test if sentinel errors are
 *    caught
 * 3: use my quicksort implementation, to test it */
#define TEST_TYPE 3

/* Stop testing after this many errors */
#define MAX_ERRORS 6

/* Set to 1 to print all pre-sort permutations */
#define VERBOSE 0

/* Max array length to test; more than 12 will take a long time */
#define MAXARRAY 10

/* Size of array for run_big_test() */
#define BIGTEST_SIZE 2000

/* Sentinels to detect buffer overruns */
#define SENTINEL_LEFT  111
#define SENTINEL_RIGHT -222


/* Used to count errors globally */
int err_ct = 0;


void run_tests(size_t N);
void run_big_test(void);
int error_check(size_t N, int *sorted);
void print_error(size_t N, int *to_sort, int *sorted);
void print_array(size_t len, int *arr);
int next_perm(int n, int *dest);
int cmp_int(const void *a, const void *b);
void quicksort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
               int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *));
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size);
void memquit(void);


int main(void)
{
    size_t len;

    srand(42);

    for (len = 0; len <= MAXARRAY; ++len)
        run_tests(len);

    run_big_test();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void run_tests(size_t N)
{
    /* Tests:
     * 1. Sort all permutations of N distinct numbers.
     * 2. Sort all permutations of N numbers with some repeated.
     * 3. Sort an array of N numbers that are all the same (may catch
     *    infinite loops or recursion).
     */

    int distinct[MAXARRAY];
    int repeats[MAXARRAY] = {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4};
    int perm[MAXARRAY];
    int to_sort[MAXARRAY];
    int sorted[MAXARRAY + 2];
    int *dataset[2];
    int i;
    int test;
    int retval;

    if (N > MAXARRAY) {
        fprintf(stderr, "run_tests(%lu) exceeds max array size.\n", N);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (int) N; ++i)
        distinct[i] = i;
    for (i = 2; i < (int) N; ++i)
        if (repeats[i] == 0)
            repeats[i] = 5;
    dataset[0] = distinct;
    dataset[1] = repeats;

    for (test = 0; test < 2; ++test) {
        while ((retval = next_perm((int) N, perm)) == 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < (int) N; ++i)
                to_sort[i] = dataset[test][perm[i]];
#if VERBOSE
            print_array(N, to_sort);
            putchar('\n');
#endif
            sorted[0] = SENTINEL_LEFT;
            memcpy(sorted + 1, to_sort, N * sizeof(int));
            sorted[N + 1] = SENTINEL_RIGHT;
            quicksort(sorted + 1, (size_t) N, sizeof(int), cmp_int);
            if (error_check(N, sorted))
                print_error(N, to_sort, sorted);
        }
        if (retval == -1)
            memquit();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (int) N; ++i)
        to_sort[i] = 6;
#if VERBOSE
    print_array(N, to_sort);
    putchar('\n');
#endif
    sorted[0] = SENTINEL_LEFT;
    memcpy(sorted + 1, to_sort, N * sizeof(int));
    sorted[N + 1] = SENTINEL_RIGHT;
    quicksort(sorted + 1, (size_t) N, sizeof(int), cmp_int);


    if (sorted[0] != SENTINEL_LEFT ||
        sorted[N + 1] != SENTINEL_RIGHT ||
        memcmp(sorted + 1, to_sort, N * sizeof(int)))
        print_error(N, to_sort, sorted);
}


void run_big_test(void)
{
    /* Create a long array of random numbers, sort it, check
     * correctness. */

    int *to_sort;
    int *sorted;
    int i;

    to_sort = malloc(BIGTEST_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    sorted = malloc((BIGTEST_SIZE + 2) * sizeof(int));
    if (!to_sort || !sorted)
        memquit();

    for (i = 0; i < BIGTEST_SIZE; ++i)
        to_sort[i] = rand() % (BIGTEST_SIZE * 4);

#if VERBOSE
    print_array(BIGTEST_SIZE, to_sort);
    putchar('\n');
#endif

    sorted[0] = SENTINEL_LEFT;
    memcpy(sorted + 1, to_sort, BIGTEST_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    sorted[BIGTEST_SIZE + 1] = SENTINEL_RIGHT;
    quicksort(sorted + 1, BIGTEST_SIZE, sizeof(int), cmp_int);
    if (error_check(BIGTEST_SIZE, sorted))
        print_error(BIGTEST_SIZE, to_sort, sorted);
}


int error_check(size_t N, int *sorted)
{
    /* Check sentinels, check that sorted part is non-decreasing */

    size_t i;

    if (sorted[0] != SENTINEL_LEFT ||
        sorted[N + 1] != SENTINEL_RIGHT)
        return 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
        if (sorted[i] < sorted[i - 1])
            return 1;

    return 0;
}


void print_error(size_t N, int *to_sort, int *sorted)
{
    /* Print pre-sort and post-sort arrays to show where error occurred.
     * Quit if MAX_ERRORS was reached. */

    printf("Error: ");
    print_array(N, to_sort);
    printf(" -> ");
    print_array(N + 2, sorted);
    putchar('\n');
    if (++err_ct >= MAX_ERRORS)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


void print_array(size_t len, int *arr)
{
    /* Pretty-print array. No newline at end. */

    char *sep = "";
    size_t i;

    putchar('(');
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            printf("%s%d", sep, arr[i]);
            sep = ", ";
    }
    putchar(')');
}


int next_perm(int passed_n, int *dest)
{
    /* Generate permutations of [0, n) in lexicographic order.
     *
     * First call: Set up, generate first permutation, return 1.
     *
     * Subsequent calls: If possible, generate next permutation and
     * return 1. If all permutations have been returned, clean up and
     * return 0. "First call" status is reset and another series may be
     * generated.
     *
     * Return -1 to indicate a memory allocation failure.
     *
     * Caller may alter the values in `dest` freely between calls, and
     * may pass a different `dest` address each time. `n` is ignored
     * after the first call.
     *
     * The function maintains static data; it can only keep track of one
     * series of permutations at a time. */

    static int *perm;
    static int new_series = 1;
    static int n;
    int i, j;

    if (new_series) {
        /* Set up first permutation, return it. */
        new_series = 0;
        n = passed_n;
        if ((perm = malloc((size_t) n * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
            return -1;
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            perm[i] = dest[i] = i;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Generate and return next permutation. First, find longest
     * descending run on right. */
    i = n - 2;
    while (i >= 0 && perm[i] > perm[i+1])
        --i;

    /* If all of perm is descending, the previous call returned the last
     * permutation. */
    if (i < 0) {
        free(perm);
        new_series = 1;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Find smallest value > perm[i] in descending run. */
    j = n - 1;
    while (perm[j] < perm[i])
        --j;

    /* Swap [i] and [j]; run will still be descending. */
    perm[i] ^= perm[j];
    perm[j] ^= perm[i];
    perm[i] ^= perm[j];

    /* Reverse the run, and we're done. */
    for (++i, j = n - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
        perm[i] ^= perm[j];
        perm[j] ^= perm[i];
        perm[i] ^= perm[j];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        dest[i] = perm[i];
    return 1;
}


int cmp_int(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* Compatible with qsort. a and b are treated as pointers to int.
     * Return value is:
     * < 0 if *a < *b
     * > 0 if *a > *b
     *   0 if *a == *b
     */

    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;

    return *aa - *bb;
}


#if TEST_TYPE == 0
/* Use qsort(3), correctly */

void quicksort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
               int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    qsort(base, nmemb, size, cmp);
}

#endif


#if TEST_TYPE == 1
/* Mess up the sort with probability 1/256 */

void quicksort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
               int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    int *ibase = base;

    qsort(base, nmemb, size, cmp);
    if (rand() % 256 == 0) {
        ibase[0] ^= ibase[nmemb - 1];
        ibase[nmemb - 1] ^= ibase[0];
        ibase[0] ^= ibase[nmemb - 1];
    }
}

#endif


#if TEST_TYPE == 2
/* Mess up one of the sentinels with probability 1/256 */

void quicksort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
               int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    int *ibase = base;
    int i;

    qsort(base, nmemb, size, cmp);
    if (rand() % 256 == 0) {
        i = (rand() % 2) ? -1 : (int) nmemb;
        ibase[i] = 42;
    }
}

#endif


#if TEST_TYPE == 3
/* Use my implementation */

void quicksort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
               int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    /* Sort array with quicksort algorithm. Pivot is always leftmost
     * element. */

    char *cbase = base;
    char *p, *q;

    if (nmemb < 2)
        return;

    /* p at element 1, just past pivot */
    p = cbase + size;

    /* q at last element */
    q = cbase + (nmemb - 1) * size;

    while (p <= q) {
        /* Move p right until *p >= pivot */
        while (p <= q && cmp(p, base) < 0)
            p += size;
        /* Move q left until *q < pivot */
        while (p <= q && cmp(q, base) >= 0)
            q -= size;
        if (p < q)
            swap(p, q, size);
    }

    /* After partitioning:
     * Pivot is element 0
     * p = q + 1 (in terms of elements)
     * Case 1: some elements < pivot, some >= pivot
     * =<<<<>>>>    q is rightmost <, p is leftmost >
     * Case 2: all elements < pivot
     * =<<<<<<<<    q is rightmost <, p is one past end
     * Case 3: all elements >= pivot
     * =>>>>>>>>    q is =, p is leftmost >
     * 
     * If not case 3:
     *     Swap pivot with q
     *     Recurse on 0 to q - 1
     * Recurse on p to nmemb - 1
     *
     * Pivot is left out of both recursive calls, so size is always
     * reduced by at least one and infinite recursion cannot occur.
     */

    if (q != cbase) {
        swap(base, q, size);
        quicksort(base, (size_t) (q - cbase) / size, size, cmp);
    }
    quicksort(p, nmemb - (size_t) (p - cbase) / size, size, cmp);
}

#endif


void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    static size_t bufsize = 0;
    static char *buf = NULL;

    if (size != bufsize) {
        bufsize = size;
        buf = realloc(buf, bufsize);
        if (!buf)
            memquit();
    }

    memcpy(buf, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, buf, size);
}


void memquit(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failure\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Oh yay, I won a Tumbleweed! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define TEST_TYPE 3
```

It would be more informative to represent this as an `enum`, with meaningfully named entries for your four test types.

```
/* Set to 1 to print all pre-sort permutations */
#define VERBOSE 0
```

No reason not to represent this as an actual boolean using `<stdbool.h>`.

Since it seems like this is the only translation unit in your project, you should set all of your functions to be `static`.

Don't pre-declare your variables at the beginning of a function; this hasn't been needed for about 20 years. e.g. rewrite your `main` loop as:

```
for (size_t len = 0; len <= MAXARRAY; len++)
```

This *especially* applies to functions like `run_tests`, with a big pile of variables at the beginning.

In `run_big_test`, you should be `free`ing `to_sort` and `sorted` after you're done with them.

This:

```
i = n - 2;
while (i >= 0 && perm[i] > perm[i+1])
    --i;
```

is better represented as a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; i--) 
    if (perm[i] <= perm[i+1])
        break;
```

I suggest that you factor out your XOR swap into a function. The compiler will be smart enough to inline it.

Comment: Thanks for all of this. Regarding pre-declarations, I’ve been using `-ansi` with `gcc` to force me to write maximally-compatible C code. Is that not really an issue these days?

Comment: You really should assume everyone has C99 or newer.